# Facebook Graph API: "Feed" no longer returns "From" (i.e. Author) Field

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently, when using the `/feed` Facebook Graph API method, it has stopped returning the `From` field. This field typically contains the `Id` and `Name` of the author of the [Facebook Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/post) in question.

The URL I'm hitting is `https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/feed?fields={my-fields-here}&access_token={token}`

From what I can tell, the `From` field still exists within the API: If I try `https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/feed?fields=id,from&access_token={token}` I get a list of `ID`s (no `From`s though), without errors.

However, if I try a deliberately-invalid field name, such as `https://graph.facebook.com/{id}/feed?fields=id,doesnotexist&access_token={token}` then I get an error response of `(#100) Unknown fields: doesnotexist`.

So the `From` field still exists as far as the Facebook Graph API is concerned. It's just no longer being returned. Did something change recently? The `From` field is also still listed as the list of fields over on their [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/post). As far as the data itself goes, posts dating months back also no longer have `From`, so it's not a case of "newer posts in the feed lack the field, but older posts do either."

I'm at a loss! If anyone could lend a hand, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It is only included if you use a Page Token. v2.11 of the Graph API (90-Day Breaking Changes):

> /page/* — User information will not be included in GET responses for
>   any objects owned by (on) a Page unless the request is made with a
>   Page access token. This affects all nodes and edges that return data
>   for objects owned by a Page.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11

...or in the link of your question:

> Any valid access token can read posts on a public Page, but responses
>   will not include User information.
>
> A Page access token can read all Posts posted to or posted by that Page, and responses will include User information.

Comment: Hm, that appears to be it. I'll see if I can't get a Page access token (hopefully using the same app / access we created, just giving it additional permissions or something along those lines) and see if that'll do it. I'm not sure if "Page Access Token" means something completely different than "give Page Access permission to current app", but we'll find out.

Comment: this will help you: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/ - of course you can only get a page token if you manage the page.